# Get a certain value in a group by statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three rows of data:

```
id       price          type
1        19.99          PERM
1        30.13          TEMP
2        14.44          SOME
```

I would like to group by the `id` and get the price, and a `TEMP` price ever exists, use that as the default. Here's an example of what the output should be:

```
id        price
1         30.13
2         14.44
```

So far I'm stuck on the `group by`:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(tp.price_value order by tp.price_type='temp' desc limit 1)
FROM prices GROUP BY id
```

How would I give priority to the price (`order by, limit 1`) in the above?

My two ideas now are to do two queries (a union seems like overkill?!) or to post-process the `group_concat` in a programming language. Neither seem too desirable, so hopefully there's a better, simpler approach here.

Comment: use having type='temp'

Comment: @saravanatn how would that work exactly?

Comment: @David542 i think you need more clarification on your question cause according to sample output your query is simple but your description is not clear plz put more data on sample

Comment: How about if `id=2` have more than one price types and both is not `'TEMP'`? Which one will it take.. first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution using a `GROUP BY` with `MAX`:

```
SELECT id, IFNULL(maxTemp, maxOther) AS maxPrice
FROM (
    SELECT id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'TEMP' THEN price ELSE NULL END) maxTemp, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN type <> 'TEMP' THEN price ELSE NULL END) maxOther
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY id
)t;
```

This solution should give you the correct results for your requirements (`ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1`).

---

But you can also use other [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to get a `SUM` or list (using `GROUP_CONCAT`) of the price values.

A solution to get the `SUM` of the price values:

```
SELECT id, IFNULL(sumTemp, sumOther) AS sumPrice
FROM (
    SELECT id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'TEMP' THEN price ELSE NULL END) sumTemp, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN type <> 'TEMP' THEN price ELSE NULL END) sumOther
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY id
)t;
```

... or to get a list of the price values using the `GROUP_CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT id, IFNULL(gTemp, gOther) AS listPrice
FROM (
    SELECT id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type = 'TEMP' THEN price ELSE NULL END) gTemp, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type <> 'TEMP' THEN price ELSE NULL END) gOther
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY id
)t;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de8f0585445fbc047511fa21353f6dd0)

Comment: Adding the fiddle :) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=95438240e7ac418da2ca2aef694b40b8

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy Was already working on a fiddle, but thank you! - If it is possible I add a fiddle and also do some testing.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch thanks for this answer. Wow, that's quite a complicated query for a relatively 'simple' task. Thanks for posting this it's quite helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a union between the id with 'TEMP'  and a query for the id with not 'TEMP'

```
  select id, price
  from  my_table 
  where type ='TEMP'
  union 
  select id, max(price) 
  from my_table m1
  inner join (
  select id from my_table where id not in (
    selet id
    from my_table 
    where  type 'TEMP'
  ) 
  group by id 
  ) t1 on t1.id= m1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using union and corelated subquery

```
  select id,max(price) as price from prices
  where type='temp' group by id
  union 
  select id,max(price) from prices t1
  where not exists( select 1 from prices t2 where t1.id=t2.id
                   and type='temp')
     group by id
```

as you need all the temp type so 1st query will take all the temp output and 2nd query will filter all the temp group

[online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=556af9eadb558cf14502002aa6659b80)

output

```
id  price
1   30.13
2   14.44
```

Comment: @nikhilsugandh why not it will take that

Comment: better fiddle it up

Comment: @nikhilsugandh i know it will work according to sample output can you plz try it on fiddle

Comment: 2  13.33 temp for one of the row your query will fail it need to show 13.33 it will show up 14.44 thank you

Comment: @nikhilsugan i got the point and edited my answer but "go on downvoting all my questions" what does it means i don't get you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192296/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-nikhil-sugandh).

Comment: @nikhilsugandh why i will delete where this answer is giving me correct result

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select * from(select a.id,a.type,
(select b.price from Table1  b where b.type=a.type and b.type in ('Temp')) mn
from Table1 a group by id,type)ab where mn is not null
union 
select id,type,max(price) from Table1
where type is not null 
and id not in(select id from(select a.id,a.type,
(select b.price from Table1  b where b.type=a.type and b.type in ('Temp')) mn
from Table1 a group by id,type)ab where mn is not null)
group by id,type;
```

check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c166a9/9

Answer (score 0):

This is by far the most hackish approach (the other two answers here are more proper answers), but you could also use a `CONCAT` statement to prepend the sort "into" the field itself. Here would be a basic example:

```
SELECT id, RIGHT(
    max(CONCAT(if(type='temp', 1,0), '^', price)),
    length(max(CONCAT(if(type='temp', 1,0), '^', price)))-2
) price FROM prices group by id

1   30.13
2   14.44
```

However, given that it doesn't rely on a subselect, could possibly perform better.